# CSS / HTML - Unable to place DIV to the right side

Tags: html, css

On our website, we have a container, with a DIV box inside which leaves a space along the right hand side so we can add some more boxes with images / text.

I got as close as the boxes to the right hand side but underneath the "main" div.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ug5pz/2/

Thanks!

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    background: #FFF;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
}
#main {
    position:relative;
    width: 450px;
    height: 300px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
}
#sidebox {
    position:relative;
    width:120px;
    height:50px;
    float:right;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="main">Welcome to our website!</div>
    <div id="sidebox">Sidebox</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not really sure what you're after, is the issue that the main box is pushing the side box down? You just need to `float:left;` it http://jsfiddle.net/Ug5pz/3/

Comment: @MLeFevre, think you nailed it

Comment: Yep, That seems to be the way to fix it! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `float:Left` to the `#main` CSS

Alternatively you could modify the `#sidebox` CSS as follows:

```
position:absolute;
right:0px;
top:0px;
```

Comment: Try adding `float:Left` to the #main

Not sure why I never tried that! I Spent hours on that yesterday! Thanks! I will mark as the Answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: You just beat me to it just 2 sec :p

Comment: It's always the way, we've all had day's like that especially with CSS, sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes :-)

Comment: It works great, except for some reason, a menu bar above those DIVs causes the main / sidebox DIVs to move around when the mouse hovers over the links.

Comment: This will be because of how the menu bar is positioned, the appearance/movement/etc of other elements on the page can affect the way in with other elements are displayed. You can use other css tricks such as the `z-index` to reduce the impact of this